# make p5.brush without webgl

Tags: processing, webgl, p5.js

is it possible to run p5.brush without WEBGL mode? When I try i get the following trace. It would be awesome if i knew which functions do need WebGL so i can maybe find a way of working without them.

```
Error: createShader() is only supported in WEBGL mode. If you'd like to use 3D graphics and WebGL, see  https://p5js.org/examples/form-3d-primitives.html for more information.
at [355]</_main.default.prototype._assert3d (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/p5.js:115767:44)

at [346]</_main.default.prototype.createShader (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/p5.js:105163:16)

at load (/p5.brush.min.js:12:180)

at N (/p5.brush.min.js:2:230)

at E (/p5.brush.min.js:2:279)

at (anonymous function) (/p5.brush.min.js:9:157)

at [298]</p5/p5.prototype.callRegisteredHooksFor (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/p5.js:62581:30)

at [298]</p5/this._setup (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/p5.js:62746:21)

at [298]</p5/this._runIfPreloadsAreDone (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/p5.js:62657:27)

at [298]</p5/this._decrementPreload (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/p5.js:62668:25)

at t< (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.8.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js:2:98292)
```